# Rendering more than 1000 textarea freezes the browser

Tags: user-interface, rendering, textarea

I was performing a task where the total number of rows to display, in the worst case, could be around 5000. I cannot use pagination here. The problem is that the browser is freezing if more than 1500 data are rendered, and after a certain time of waiting (around 2–3 minutes), it is rendering all the data and the page is becoming responsive again. After a bit of investigation, I found out that it is the textarea that is causing the browser to take this long amount of time to render. Is there any way to fix this issue so that textarea rendering will not take much time considering that I have to render more than 3000 rows at a time?

[image]

[image]